# If I have existing nodejs web app how can i configure it with hyperledger?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

As hyperledger is an enterprise blockchain solution so it does not make any sense to create a complete application from scratch, are there any resources available to explore integrating hyperledger with existing applications(specifically MEAN application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for integrating Hyperledger Fabric with the MEAN stack:

1) The Fabric Node SDK:  https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io
2) If the Hyperledger Fabric smart contracts are built with Hyperledger Composer, Composer generates a REST API which can then be easily integrated with existing MEAN applications